# why this jquery code is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in jquery . I don't know why this code is not working . I have 3 dropdown box. Depending on f_cat1 and f_cat2 , f_university_name will be fetched , as f_cat1 and f_cat2 can't be empty that's why i am checking if f_university_name is empty , trying to gathering data in it . or f_cat1 or f_cat2 is changed , also trying to do this operation.

Would you anyone please help me? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var cat1= $('#f_cat1').val();    // f_cat1,f_cat2 is the id of a dropdown box 
     var cat2= $('#f_cat2').val();

     $('#f_cat1').change(make_change);
     $('#f_cat2').change(make_change);

     var uni_name= $('#f_university_name').val();  
     if(uni_name=="")
     {
         make_change();
     }

});

function make_change()
{
    var post_url ="<?php echo $c_link.'get_university/';?>"+ cat1+'/'+cat2;
    //  alert(post_url);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        //  dataType : "JSON",
        success: function(unis) 
        {
           //  alert('hi');
           $('#f_university_name').empty();
           $.each(unis,function(university_id,university_name)
           {
              var opt = $('<option/>'); 
              opt.val(university_id);
              opt.text(university_name);

              $('#f_university_name').append(opt);
           });


     } //end success
  }); //end AJAX
}
```

After edit1 : Thanks to all for replying me , it has started to work . But the problem is i am unable to comment my reputation is low . I am new to stack overflow , i didn't know about rules . And  i am unable to click anything.... how could i get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no varianbles `cat_1` and `cat_2` in your function `make_change`, because they are local in `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`. Move the defenition of `make_change` function into `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` block, then you'll have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Place your variables outside the document.ready function. Means global access. Then you can use them whereever you want

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're going to have here is that you read the values of `f_cat1` and `f_cat2` when the page first loads, and never read them again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var cat1= $('#f_cat1').val();    // f_cat1,f_cat2 is the id of a dropdown box 
     var cat2= $('#f_cat2').val();

     ....
```

This means that whatever the values of those 2 dropdowns were at the start, the variables `cat1` and `cat2` will never change.

The easiet way to fix this, is to read those variables every thim you call the function `make_change`:

```
function make_change()
{
    var cat1= $('#f_cat1').val();    
    var cat2= $('#f_cat2').val();
    var post_url ="<?php echo $c_link.'get_university/';?>"+ cat1+'/'+cat2;
    ....
```